# Extreme visual glitch after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: graphics

I'm a relatively new Linux user, and after upgrading my laptop from 19.04 to 20.04 from a live USB, once logging in, there is an extreme graphical distortion diagonally across the desktop. The mouse is unaffected by this glitch, but everything else on the desktop, including windows, are. It's all but unusable in this state. I've tried rebooting several times, updating and purging entirely my graphics drivers, but nothing works. I even tried creating a new user, as the glitch does not occur on the login screen, but it persists on all other accounts. This is on an HP laptop, unsure of the model.
Apparently I need 10 reputation to post images, but here's a link to a photo taken on my phone, at least. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AEdkYli5B7fmIjLFMz6hHacNyQ9gCbHz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: 19.04 to 20.04 was never a supported path to upgrade because 19.04 had already reached end of life when 20.04 was released.  You should probably re-install the operating system cleanly.  If you do not want to be forced to upgrade every 6 months, I suggest sticking with LTS releases which are supported at least 3 years from release.  See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: That's precisely what I did. I reinstalled Ubuntu as though from scratch in a new partition, after realising 19.04 was at EOL far too late.

Comment: This looks like GPU artifacting.  Usually this is a sign of hardware on it's way out but sometimes it could be driver/software related, though that's pretty unlikely with a fresh clean install. Are you sure the installation media is valid? An ISO is a large file that can get corrupted in transit. You might want to try BitTorrent protocol which automatically verifies downloads - https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads - You can also use BalenaEtcher to flash the ISO to a USB - it's simple to use, and hard to go wrong - it also auto verifies the flash.

Comment: After that you might want to reinstall - make sure you are connected to the internet and make sure you select the option to download updates during install, and also to get 3rd party software -- so your GPU driver can be installed right from the beginning (hopefully)